# Не могу запустить службу WCF ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, веб-служба

Создал пустой ASP.NET проект. По [туториалу](https://tproger.ru/translations/restful-service-asp-net/#1) добавил службу WCF и написал этот код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace NaotvetWebService
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class TestService
    {
        private static List<string> lst = new List<string>
        {
            "Arrays",
            "Queues",
            "Stacks"
        };

        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Tutorial")]

        public string GetAllTutorials() => String.Join(",", lst);

        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Tutorial/{TutorialId}")]

        public string GetTutorialByID(string TutorialId)
        {
            int pid;
            if (!int.TryParse(TutorialId, out pid))
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            return lst[pid];
        }

        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            UriTemplate = "/Tutorial", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]

        public void AddTutorial(string str) => lst.Add(str);

        [WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            UriTemplate = "/Tutorial/{TutorialId}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]

        public void DeleteTutorial(string TutorialId)
        {
            int pid;
            if (!int.TryParse(TutorialId, out pid))
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            lst.RemoveAt(pid);
        }
    }
}
```

И вот конфиг:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--
  Дополнительные сведения о настройке приложения ASP.NET см. на странице
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433.
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="NaotvetWebService.TestServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="NaotvetWebService.TestService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="NaotvetWebService.TestServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="NaotvetWebService.TestService" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer></configuration>
```

Но при запуске меня встречает вот такая ошибка: "Не удалось добавить службу. Метаданные службы недоступны. Убедитесь, что служба работает и предоставляет метаданные". И при запуске это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Что делать?**

Comment: Это при обращении по какому адресу?

Comment: я нажимаю в студии запустить  (IIS Google Chrome), ссылка: localhost:цыфры/любая страница, даже если запрос по типу localhost:цыфры/TestService.svc/Tutorial

Comment: В том туториале, ссылку на который Вы привели, есть раздел "Тестирование вб-сервиса". Я почти уверен,что написанный Вами сервис этого тестирования не проходит. Нужно искть проблему, скорее всего, связнную с запуском проекта в среде VS. Посмотреть в консоль - может, там появляются сообщения об ошибках. Выключить, а лучше - удалить антивирус. Проверить, что выключен брандуэр виндовс. Попробовать зпустить сттический сайт из одного файла deault.html на IIS и убедиться, что всё работает. Всё это увеличит шансы на запуск проекта

Comment: Вообще, по личному впечтлению человека (меня), который две недели выплясывал вокруг WCF в попытках его запустить, скажу сразу: очень замороченная штука, в которой реально плохо понятно, куда коней запрягать. Простые RESTful интерфейсы гораздо проще, не требуют никакого конфига и тестируюится с помощью постмена.

Comment: @S.H. таже ошибка в проэкте web api

Comment: Статический сайт открывается?